# How to select inner text of the link using XPath?

Tags: javascript, css, xpath, scrapy, href

I am using `Scrapy` to crawl data.

On `JS` console on my browser, I type `$x('//div[@class="summary"]//div[contains(@class, "tags")]')` to get what I need, but I need to filter the data.

The following picture is the `$x('//div[@class="summary"]//div[contains(@class, "tags")]')` command result.

[image: JS console result]

How should I write `xpath` command to get the data in the green box? I tried `$x('//div[@class="summary"]//div[contains(@class, "tags")]//a[contains(@class, "post-tag")]')`, but that is not what I want。

Thank you!

Comment: why did you skip 'python-2.7'? what is the logic behind? (I assume it is what you mean by 'not what I need')

Comment: @har07, I need to to get the correct xpath script to filter the data in JS console. see  [xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp)

Comment: @har07, sorry, I forgot to put a box on it. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To select inner text of `<a>` element within the selected `div`, you only need to append `/a/text()` to your XPath which selects the `div` :

```
//div[@class="summary"]//div[contains(@class, "tags")]/a/text()
```